# How would I print out the Keys and Values in this hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
 public class myclass
{
 public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int array1[] = new int[4];
     System.out.println("Enter some integers");
     for(int i = 0; i <array1.length; i++){
         array1[i] = scan.nextInt();
 }
 Arrays.sort(array1);
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("IdOne", array1[0]);
    map.put("IdOne", array1[1]);
    map.put("IdOne", array1[2]);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to print the values that I entered into the array along with a key from the Hashmap.
Example output:

Enter some integers

3

5

2

IdOne 2

IdOne 3

IdOne 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the entries

```
someMap.entries();
```

then loop over them

```
for (Map.Entry entry : someMap.entries()) {
    // do something
}
```

then print out the key and the value

```
for (Map.Entry entry : someMap.entries()) {
    System.out.println("key: %s, value: %s\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Note that your map is being using incorrectly.  Entries in a map have a "key" which is logically the "location" used to access or update a "value".  By putting all the values into the same location (`IdOne`) you are assuring that prior values are being overwritten.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for  a way to assign one Key to a group of values? Is there anything other than a hashmap that could allow me to do this?

Comment: A "map" is a type of math function, defined such that one key only returns one value.  What you want is one key that might return one, two, or more values.  I would recommend a map that returns a collection, and then add the values to the collection "value" within the map.